# connecting to firebase using android

Tags: android, json, firebase

I recently started a project where I save data to firebase in Android studio. I have a function that saves data like so

```
private fun heroSave (){
        val name = editTextName.text.toString().trim()
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("heroes")

        val heroId = ref.push().key.toString()
        val hero = Hero(heroId, name, ratingBar.rating.toInt())
        ref.child(heroId).setValue(hero).addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "hero saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } }
```

Every time I've tried to connect the sdk setup says "Checking if the app has communicated with our servers", and it won't connect. I have downloaded the google json file and set up my build gradle and app build gradle perfectly. Also, I have added to the xml file 'uses internet permission.' What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you tried running the app on the android emulator or a real android  ?

Comment: Have you saved the google-services.json file in the correct directory?

Comment: i put my google-services.json file in the app root directory

Comment: yes, i have tried running on an emulator

Comment: could you be specific, which directory is google-services.json supposed to be in?